# How to use rowspan in report? | Qweb, Odoo 10

Tags: html-table, odoo-10, qweb

Help me! My code xml file in field ngày giao:

```
<td  t-att-rowspan="len(layout_category['lines'])">
    <span t-field="doc.date_order"/> 
 </td>
```

I want to combine it into one row, But I'm having the same problem Plese!! help me!

[Unedited Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwRMp.png)

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are thinking of `colspan` rather than `rowspan`.

Try it with `t-att-colspan` instead.